# Angular Attribute Binding via attr. results in null values when using @Attribute

Tags: html, angular, binding, attributes

If I use an angular component like this in my template:

```
<my-cmp selectable />
```

And my component asks the following in its constructor:

```
constructor(@Attribute("selectable") selectable: string){};
```

Then `selectable` will be an empty string, as expected, but when it is used like this:

```
<my-cmp [attr.selectable]="true" />
```

This will place the attribute correctly to my tag in the DOM and result in the following:

```
<my-cmp selectable="true" />
```

But in this case `selectable` will always have a `null` value, regardless if it is on `construct` or on `ngOnInit` and of its given value (e.g. `false`, "" or anything else will also result in `null`).

The question here is: why?
And more important: how to use boolean attributes in angular the best way?

Note: I explicitly don't want to use **property-binding** in this case, the given "input" should be static.

Answer (score 1):

You can have some insight for the internals concerning @Attribute decorator [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1858#issuecomment-151326461) :

> Angular does not read attribute values during runtime, only during
>   compile time, as otherwise we would get a performance hit.

With the `<my-cmp [attr.selectable]="true" />` syntax, your are creating a binding. But the attribute value will be set after the first change detection cycle. So at compile time you will not have the attribute set, so you get a `null` value.

Comment: Thank you for this information. It is kind of counterintuitive :(

So in angular I can't dynamically add attributes to components on itself? I would have to use if else statements with static attribute tags attached to my components?

    <ng-container *ngIf="selectable; else #notselectable">
        <my-cmp selectable />
    </ng-container>

Comment: you can, but Attribute decorator is for a static attribute value, not a bound one. It handles with great performance a specific use case ( with an exception for top-level components). If you attribute is dynamic, you have to use the Input decorator and the ngOnChange lyfecycle hook

Comment: The attribute is static by itself, but it is dynamic in the sense it can be set or not. And its defined at compile time, no changes allowed afterwards.
How would you pass static "inputs" to your component?

Comment: then you can use the Attribute decorator if <my-cmp selectable> then selectable value will be empty string in the decorator, if <my-cmp> the selectable value will be null in the constructor. So you can distinguish between your two cases

Comment: Yeah, that's true, but how do I write this to my template?
As I already mentioned, if `selectable` can be set to true or false, I would have to switch and write my <my-cmp> inside if else statements as I mentioned in my first comment?
One with the tag attached, and one without?
And what happens if I add a second or third boolean attribute to the mix? The if else statements had to be nested to a horrible code?

Comment: sorry i misunderstood what you said in your previous comment. If the selectable attribute value is set dynamically by the parent component you cant use Attribute decorator and needs the Input decorator ( but if you know for sure it will not change, you can just read the value in the ngOnInit and forget about ngOnChange )